# iOS unwrapping SystemSound

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I stored an Int in UserDefaults. The Int will serve as the index of `audioOptionsList`, an array of objects, each having a SystemSoundID property.

This crashes with error: `Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x7fff87b33c28) to 'NSNumber' (0x7fff87bf4e00).`

```
    var soundToPlay = SystemSoundID(1322)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "timerSoundSelection") != nil {
            
            let storedIndex = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "timerSoundSelection")!
            print("stored index is: \(storedIndex)") //prints a non-optional int as expected.
            soundToPlay = audioOptionsList[storedIndex as! Int].sound //crashes with error
            
        } else {
            soundToPlay = SystemSoundID(1322)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is stored as a `String` not an `Int` , use `string(forKey:` then cast it

```
if let stored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timerSoundSelection") 
 , let value = Int(stored) { }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought casting it like I did would work.